# On button click the button do different task(HTML)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Now in my page i setup a dynamic grid boxes are there and in each boxes a button is there.. my motive is onclick o the button every button perform a different task but in my code every button perform the similar task.
and the second thing is that how can i generate the dynamic id of buttons
now here my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"> 
 <title>Digital Menu</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css"> 

   <title>Page Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<div class="banner">
  <div class="header">
<div class="header-inner container clear">
 <a class="logo" href="#"><span class="sr">Lambda Logo</span></a>     
  <div class="navigation">
    <ul class="navigation-menu">         
      <li class="navigation-item"><a href="new_orders.php">New Orders</a>
   </li>
      <li class="navigation-item"><a href="#open_orders">Open Orders</a>
    </li>
        <li class="navigation-item"><a href="#complete_orders">Complete
    Orders</a></li>         
    </ul>            
  </div>
  <ul>
    <h1>open orders</h1>
    </ul>       
</div>
</div>


 <?php

  include("connect.php");
   $query="SELECT * FROM `orders`";
   $filter_Result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($filter_Result)){




        echo "<div class='block'>";

      echo "<div class='boxed'>";

 echo "<div id='container'>";


   echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>" ."<br>"; 
  echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>"."<br>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['created_date'] . "</td>"."<br>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['uid'] . "</td>"."<br>"."<br>"."<br>"."<br>";
  echo "<button class='button' style='vertical-align:middle' id='demo'
    onclick='myFunction()'><span>click Me</span>";
 echo "</button>";



 echo "</div>";


      echo "</div>";

    echo "</div>";


  }

      ?>


   <script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction() {
     document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'Hello World';
     }
  </script>


  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass unique value with your ID and function parameter. Refer this code. This will set unique ID for each button and carries that unique id as parameter in the function. So the function will display the message '**Hello World**' with the ID.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8"> 
   <title>Digital Menu</title>
   <meta name="description" content="">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css"> 
   <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="banner">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header-inner container clear">
      <a class="logo" href="#"><span class="sr">Lambda Logo</span></a>     
        <div class="navigation">
          <ul class="navigation-menu">         
             <li class="navigation-item"><a href="new_orders.php">New Orders</a></li>
             <li class="navigation-item"><a href="#open_orders">Open Orders</a></li>
             <li class="navigation-item"><a href="#complete_orders">Complete Orders</a></li>         
          </ul>            
        </div>
        <ul><h1>open orders</h1></ul>       
     </div>
  </div>
 <?php
  include("connect.php");
  $query="SELECT * FROM `orders`";
  $filter_Result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
  $div = '';

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($filter_Result)){
      $div .= "<div class='block'><div class='boxed'><div id='container'>";
      $div .= "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>" ."<br>"; 
      $div .= "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>"."<br>";
      $div .= "<td>" . $row['created_date'] . "</td>"."<br>";
      $div .= "<td>" . $row['uid'] . "</td>"."<br>"."<br>"."<br>"."<br>";
      $div .= "<button class='button' style='vertical-align:middle' id='demo" . $row['id'] . "' onclick='myFunction(\"" . $row['id'] . "\")'><span>click Me</span>";
      $div .= "</button></div></div></div>";
  }

  echo $div;
 ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function myFunction(id) {
     document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'Hello World' + id;
   }
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, if you want to perform different action for each button, then you can write the corresponding action using **if** or **switch** condition in the function.

**For eg :**

```
function myFunction(id) {
  if( id == 1 ) {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'First Button clicked';
  } else if( id == 1 ) {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'Second Button clicked';
  }
}
```